# How to match records where value is either zero or one and greater

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I have a MySQL table with an `INT` column `c` that has a value of 0 or anything greater.

My `SELECT` statement contains a variable `$x` for querying the table that is either 1 or 0. I want to be able to match records where `c` = 0 if `$x` is 0, or `c` >= 1 if `$x` is 1.

This is how I'm currently doing it in Perl:

```
my $x; # 1 or 0
my $c_statement;
if ($x==0){$c_statement = 'c = 0'}else{$c_statement = 'c >= 1'};
my $sth = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE $c_statement";
```

Is there a neater way to do this without having to evaluate `$x` beforehand or using `IF` clauses in the `WHERE` statement?

Comment: How about using `CASE`?

Answer (score 1):

Just:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE 
    (:x = 0 AND c = 0)
    OR (:x = 1 AND c >= 1)
```

The parentheses are superfluous (since `OR` has lower precedence than `AND`), but I find that they make the logic of the condtions clearer.